# Determine value of variables at hit breakpoint in Android Studio

Tags: debugging, android-studio, breakpoints

```
...
BREAKPOINT `int i = 10 + 12;`
...
```

When I add a break point to code in Android Studio as above, AS will run to the line I added the break point to, as expected. However, if there is no code after the break point line I can't see what `i` resolves to in the debugger. I can fix this problem by inserting a single line of dummy code, but there must be an easier/more elegant way to get around this problem that I'm missing.

How can I avoid adding a dummy line of code to view these values?

EDIT: I'm using the latest version of Android Studio (1.0.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's possible to put a breakpoint on the line following the last line you want executed.**

A breakpoint stops execution before the line under the breakpoint is executed.

In the example above, a new variable is introduced (`i`), which is as yet unknown to the interpreter. It's necessary to step-over (execute) the line of code in order for this variable to be initialized.

See the example below, in which there's a test function that contains the line of code from the question:

[image: Hit breakpoint]

I've put breakpoints on the start brace of the function `{`, the line in question, and the end brace `}`. Note that there's an X on the first breakpoint, as it's invalid. The current execution point is on (or just before execution of) the dark-blue highlited line. Note that the variable `i` does not exist in the Variables window below.

When I step over (execute) the line of code, the active line is now over the final brace in the function `}`, and that the variable `i` is now initialized and set:

[image: At final brace in function]

So, if you're interested in breaking *after* a given line of code, just put the breakpoint *after* that line of code, even if that line is the final brace of a function.

Note: this won't work if there is an exit statement (e.g. `break`, `return` etc.) as the final executed line of code in a function.